# Intercept python's `print` statement and display in GUI

Tags: python

I have this somewhat complicated command line function in Python (lets call it `myFunction()`), and I am working to integrate it in a graphical interface (using PySide/Qt).

The GUI is used to help select inputs, and display outputs. However, `myFunction` is designed to work as a stand-alone command line function, and it occasionnaly prints out the progress.

My question is: how can I intercept these `print` calls and display them in the GUI?
I know it would be possible to modify `myFunction()` to send `processEvents()` to the GUI, but I would then lose the ability to execute `myFunction()` in a terminal.

Ideally, I would like something similar to Ubuntu's graphical software updater, which has a small embeded terminal-looking widget displaying what `apt-get` would display were it executed in a terminal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could redirect stdout and restore after.  for example:

```
import StringIO
import sys

# somewhere to store output
out = StringIO.StringIO()

# set stdout to our StringIO instance
sys.stdout = out

# print something (nothing will print)
print 'herp derp'

# restore stdout so we can really print (__stdout__ stores the original stdout)
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

# print the stored value from previous print
print out.getvalue()
```

Comment: From preliminary testing, this seems to be what I'm looking for. I can intercept the output of `print` and store it in a variable. Now I just need to find a way to display it such that my GUI doesn't look like it freezes, but that's for another question!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Python 3 pattern using contextmanager that both encapsulates [the monkey-patch technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17067799/39396) and also ensures that `sys.stdout` is restored in case of an exception.

```
from io import StringIO
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def capture_stdout():
    """
    context manager encapsulating a pattern for capturing stdout writes
    and restoring sys.stdout even upon exceptions

    Examples:
    >>> with capture_stdout() as get_value:
    >>>     print("here is a print")
    >>>     captured = get_value()
    >>> print('Gotcha: ' + captured)

    >>> with capture_stdout() as get_value:
    >>>     print("here is a print")
    >>>     raise Exception('oh no!')
    >>> print('Does printing still work?')
    """
    # Redirect sys.stdout
    out = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = out
    # Yield a method clients can use to obtain the value
    try:
        yield out.getvalue
    finally:
        # Restore the normal stdout
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it with a function that hijacks stdout:

```
def stdin2file(func, file):
  def innerfunc(*args, **kwargs):
    old = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = file
    try:
      return func(*args, **kwargs)
    finally:
      sys.stdout = old
  return innerfunc
```

Then simply provide a file like object that supports `write()`:

```
class GUIWriter:
  def write(self, stuff):
    #send stuff to GUI

MyFunction = stdin2file(MyFunction, GUIWriter())
```

The wrapper can be turned into a decorator too:

```
def redirect_stdin(file):
  def stdin2file(func, file):
    def innerfunc(*args, **kwargs):
      old = sys.stdout
      sys.stdout = file
      try:
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      finally:
        sys.stdout = old
    return innerfunc
  return stdin2file
```

The use it when declaring `MyFunction()`:

```
@redirect_stdin(GUIWriter())
def MyFunction(a, b, c, d):
  # any calls to print will call the 'write' method of the GUIWriter
  # do stuff
```

Comment: thanks, very helpful. just `def stdin2file(func,file)` has subtle error: `file` parameter causes error when trying to use `redirect_stdin` as a decorator, so it should be `def stdin2file(func)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

All printing is done via `sys.stdout`, which is a ordinary file-like object: iirc, it requires a method `write(str)`.  As long as your replacement has that method, it's quite easy to drop in your hook:

```
import sys

class CaptureOutput:
    def write(self, message):
        log_message_to_textbox(message)

sys.stdout = CaptureOutput()
```

The actual contents of `log_message_to_textbox` are up to you.